# How to execute a function AFTER Event.observe(n,"click",respondClick)

Tags: javascript, events, function, prototypejs

My function `Event.observe(n,"click",respondClick)` execute `respondClick` **ON** click.

But I need to execute `respondclick` **AFTER** click

I need to get height of my div **AFTER** I clicked. But this function get the height of my div instantaneously.

Is it possible ?

```
Event.observe(n, 'click', function(e){
  var height = $("hello").getHeight();
  alert(height);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by `after`. Could you use the `mouseup` event, which is fired when the user releases the mouse button?

You could `setTimeout`, and run the function a short time after the user has clicked. If `responseClick` changes the UI this would make the page feel sluggish though.

Comment: @Steffi I can't think of an immediate way to do this, but as the tags you have choosen suggest, it may be possible to hook in to execute after the 'click' event using some clever code. However, if possible it would be easier to hook into whatever function is changing the dimensions of the `div` (and execute `respondClick` after that function) rather than hooking into the same event from two places.

Comment: @Steffi Be very careful with that. You have something of a race condition there - you don't know that the `setTimeout` delay is long enough for the function that changes the size of the `div` to execute.

Comment: If you're going to use this approach, then [Function#delay](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/delay/) is a more prototypey way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Your "AFTER click" doesn't make any sense, unless the click is doing something else as well, in which case the answer will depend what that "something else" is, and how you do it.

But it is possible that Function#defer() will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for `defer()`, I didn't know.